# How to separate commas into separate row from laravel form add?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

---

I am getting `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given` this error when i use `explode()` to add in mysql database

---

Here is my code

```
$tags = new Tag;

$commas = "test,hello,hi";
$separate_tags = explode(',', $commas);
$tags->tag_name = $separate_tags;

$tags->save();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here issue is you are trying to insert an array as string. To save this you have too do this as given below:

```
$commas = "test,hello,hi";
$separate_tags = explode(',', $commas);

foreach($separate_tags as $separate_tag){
  $tags = new Tag;
  $tags->tag_name = $separate_tag;
  $tags->save();
}
```